# facing issue with Install the Heroku CLI on Ubuntu 18 with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, heroku

I am trying to run heroku on my terminal  with `heroku login` command but everytime it show me this message

```
Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com
```

If i do `heroku -v` , `heroku run rails c` in all command it show me this same error

i did Gem install heroku it id done successfully.

than after same error everytime

Please help me to find solution about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install the heroku CLI through rubygems (`gem install`).

You have to install following the guide here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install

On Ubuntu install it with the following command: `sudo snap install heroku --classic`

On MacOS, if you have Homebrew installed, run `brew install heroku/brew/heroku`, otherwise download an installer and install Heroku using it.

Comment: i did it still getting same msg => Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Heroku CLI, you need to install heroku in your ubuntu system.
on ubuntu 16+ versions you can install heroku cli with below command.

```
sudo snap install heroku --classic
```

you can't use any heroku command until its installed in your system

Comment: I did this already it show me that heroku is already installed but after then i am facing same error as above in the question.

Comment: @P_M uninstall gem heroku `gem uninstall heroku` with this command. then check the version of heroku.

Comment: again getting the same error like it show that it is uninstalled but it fills it is still there ?

Comment: can you please add the log of `gem uninstall heroku` ? with this command you installed heroku gem in your whole system

Comment: I used curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
command and it says eroku installed succesfully, After that i did herou -v again it show me "Install the Heroku CLI from https://cli.heroku.com"

Comment: try this line `sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
` and then fire `heroku apps` command